# When loading "https" url in android web view, getting connection timeout error

Tags: android-webview, webviewclient

When i am trying to load https url it results a blank page. I overrided onReceivedSslError method in webviewclient but this overrided method is never executing. Also I overrided onReceivedError method in which i am getting CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT as error description argument.

```
@Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        handler.proceed(); 
    }

@Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), description, 200).show();
    }
```